# How to change the default paper size in windows programmatically?

Tags: winapi, printing

How to change the default paper size in windows programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `dmPaperSize` member of the `DEVMODE` member of the `PRINTER_DEFAULTS` structure passed to `OpenPrinter`.

[Here's a code sample](http://www.novapdf.com/kb/how-to-set-programmatically-the-page-related-settings-page-size-layout-via-novapdf-sdk-112.html).